# How to display my database created with EF Code First in DataGridView?

Tags: c#, winforms, entity-framework, datagridview

I'm trying to display one of my DB's table in a DataGridView. I created the database using EF Code First approach. Here are my DB classes:

```
public class BloodDonor
{
    public int BloodDonorId { get; set; }
    public String FirstName { get; set; }
    public String LastName { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateofBirth { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateOfRegistration { get; set; }
    public BloodTypes BloodType { get; set; }

    public virtual List<BloodDonation> BloodDonations { get; set; }


}

public class BloodDonation
{
    public int BloodDonationId { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateOfDonation { get; set; }

    public virtual BloodDonor bloodDonor { get; set; }
}

public class BloodBankContext: DbContext
{
    public BloodBankContext() : base("BloodBankDatabase1") 
    {
        Database.SetInitializer<BloodBankContext>(new DropCreateDatabaseAlways<BloodBankContext>());
    }
    public DbSet<BloodDonor> BloodDonors { get; set; }
    public DbSet<BloodDonation> BloodDonations { get; set; }

}
```

Here's my main Form:

```
public partial class BloodBankManager : Form
{
    public static BloodBankContext context;



    public BloodBankManager()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        context = new BloodBankContext();



        ExampleDataFiller exampleDataFiller = new ExampleDataFiller(context);
        var query = from b in context.BloodDonors
                    select b;

        foreach (var donor in query)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(donor.BloodDonorId + " " + donor.FirstName + " " + donor.LastName + " " + donor.DateofBirth.ToShortDateString() + " " + donor.BloodType);
        }

    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


    }

    private void newBloodDonorButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        NewBloodDonorForm newBloodDonorForm = new NewBloodDonorForm();
        newBloodDonorForm.bloodBankManager = this;
        newBloodDonorForm.Show();
    }


}
```

My DB seems to work fine, but I got no idea how to display the

```
context.BloodDonors
```

in DataGridView. I tried using the DataSource wizard in DataGridViewProperty, but after I run the application for the first time the DataGridView wouldnt update after altering the BloodDonors table. Any ideas on easiest possible way of attaching wanted table to DataGridView?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to bind to `DataGridView.DataSource` property.

Read more here 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.datasource(v=vs.110).aspx

Here is a code example

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace WindowsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string connectionString = "Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=pubs;Integrated Security=True";
            string sql = "SELECT * FROM Authors";
            SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
            SqlDataAdapter dataadapter = new SqlDataAdapter(sql, connection);
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            connection.Open();
            dataadapter.Fill(ds, "Authors_table");
            connection.Close();
            dataGridView1.DataSource = ds;
            dataGridView1.DataMember = "Authors_table";
        }
    }
}
```

Here is another link with more information on [binding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fbk67b6z(v=vs.90).aspx)

Comment: Thx for your effort. Apparently what I was looking for is smth like this: dataGridView1.DataSource = context.BloodDonors.Local.ToBindingList(); Works fine now :)